# A game where two players alternate turns and subtract $1$ or a prime that divides $n$ until $n=0$

Tags: number-theory

A game where one two players try to win by alternating turns. An arbitrary $n$ is given. Each turn, one can either subtract 1 or a prime that divides n. The player who is left with $n=0$ loses. For what values of $n$ will the first player win for certain?

For this question, I first tried computing the first few terms, and try to prove by strong induction that all multiples of $4$ are certain losses for whoever's turn it is. However, I found it extremely difficult to prove that when $n=4k+3$, one can subtract a prime that divides $4k+3$ and create a new number that is a multiple of 4. Can anyone help?

Comment: If $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$ then it can't be the case that all the primes which divide $n$ are of the form $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, so there must be at least one prime factor of $n$ of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: That is definitely right, and therefore proves the question. I feel like there may be a solution that can be achieved without the use of strong induction, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, these things always come down to induction.

Comment: Once you've subtracted the prime (or $1$), does the next player subtract ($1$ or) another prime dividing the *original* $n$ or dividing this *new* $n$?

Comment: the new $n$ after a subtraction